# Add setting processData and contentType to $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I make file uploading in WordPress using `$.post()`, i not use `$.ajax()` because not working on Chrome for Android 4, so i use `$.post()`.

But problems here, i can't handle file upload use`$.post()`, only give an error `TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.`

This my code.

```
<input type="file" id="attachment-upload" name="attachment-upload" multiple />

// start uploading
$( document ).on( 'change', '#attachment-upload', function(e) {
    // get file
    var file = e.target.files;

    var ajax_data = {
        action: 'upload_new_attachment',
        file: file,
    }

    // ajax actions
    $.post( ajaxurl, ajax_data, function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    }, 'json' );
});
```

In another tutorial i see use `$.ajax()` with setting `processData: false` and `contentType: false`.

Now, how put setting `processData: false` and `contentType: false` for `$.post()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mixing post and ajax?

Comment: so, can you tell me what the best method?